# Inhabilitar la escritura durante la ejecución del programa

Tags: python, input, keyboard

Quiero que mientras se esté ejecutando el programa, todas las teclas que escriba se ignoren.
En un ejemplo sencillo, el problema que quiero solucionar es el siguiente.

```
from time import sleep
sleep(5)
```

Si escribo algo durante esos 5 segundos, lo que haya escrito me aparecerá cuando se termine ese tiempo. En este caso se escribirá en la línea de comandos.

Este hecho me repercute a la hora de crear varios threads/hilos en el que uno se dedica a hacer un print varias veces durante varios segundos y cuando termina el otro hilo hace un input.
En otro ejemplo simple sería similar a esto:

```
from time import sleep
sleep(5) # Si escribo algo aquí y presiono 'Enter', nada más acabar los 5 segundos el input se autorrellenara
entrada=input('Escribe algo: ')
```